# What difficulty is "Kyle"?

Tags: killer-instinct-2013

In Killer Instinct for XB1, you can select difficulty "Kyle", the thing is the difficulty setting continuously loops (go from easiest in the same direction and it loops back to easiest.

So what actually is Kyle? hard? easy?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

"The Kyle difficulty level is the most difficult setting, and is based on one of the development team's AI Designers, who is apparently insanely good at the game."

Source: http://www.eventhubs.com/news/2013/oct/16/killer-instincts-training-mode-features-full-hitbox-displays-kyle-difficulty-setting-seamlessly-endless-recordplayback-function-and-more/

"The KI difficulties are listed as Noob, Easy, Medium, Hard, Killer, and something referred to as "Kyle."

Comment: so never go against Kyle, got it.

Comment: Hahaha, doesn't hurt to try it at least once :P

Comment: update: went against Kyle. It broke **any** attempt at a combo. Would also counter break all of my combo breaks. painful time was had.

Comment: At least you tried and didn't throw you controller at the TV.

Comment: @Rapitor The interesting thing is that counter-breakers can't be done on reaction to a combo-break, so Kyle (and all other difficulties to a lesser extent) actually learn how you play and when you're likely to combo break.